# Can I change encryption_key in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was developing website in code igniter and in development phase i have set encryption_key which was not strong, Now i want to change it to strong encryption_key as site is going to live, Is there any issue or problem which can occur by doing this?

**EDIT**

actually in codeigniter doc reffering :
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html
it is mention that "In fact, the key you chose will provide the only means to decode data that was encrypted with that key, so not only must you choose the key carefully, you must never change it if you intend use it for persistent data."

but i have changed on local and not seems any issue yet.
Thanks.

Comment: Only one way to find out!

Comment: im being facetious, nobody can tell you how **you** used the encryption_key, so change it and test before going live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$config['encryption_key']` kept as configuration so that you can change it.If you can't change it,it would not be a configuration.

If you look at the comments before `$config['encryption_key']` it says

> If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key.
>
> See the user guide for more info.

See details at documentation how to setup [encryption key](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html#setting-your-encryption-key)

Comment: From the docs `you must never change it if you intend use it for persistent data` which means it is **not always editable** beacuase it will brick the encrypted data you have saved in db etc. **IF ANY**, which most people don't keep, but still a check is required before proceeeding.

Comment: It does not mean you cannot change it.It means if you encrypted some data with one key and stored it then you changed the key,the stored data will not return right value for decryption.So you have to be careful if you stored data.

Comment: thats exactly what i meant by **bricking data**. it is editable but not sensible in such cases. its not matter of fact that can that file be edited (which is obvious true you can edit a config file anytime) but will it harm thats a concern.

Comment: yes you both right, u expanded my knowlege, my main point was also to know that will it harm or not, now i understood that in which case it will be harmfull, one more thing encrypted data only saves into session table in db ?

Comment: At CI-3 I don't see any relation with session and encryption_key.But when I worked at CI-2 I saw encryption_key is needed to use session class.But not sure session does anything with encryption_key.

Comment: AFAIK Its there basically for encrypting the session cookie. `$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']` in CI-2, which is not present in CI-3.